# Python complaining that a SWIG module doesn't exists

Tags: c++, python, linux, swig

Following the different tutorials on the web, I have tried to make a wrapper of a c++ class in python, using SWIG.

My class looks like this:

```
/*file libraryInstance.h*/
struct LibraryInstance
{
    void init();
    void terminate();
private:
    std::shared_ptr<AnObject> m_spAnObject;
};
```

For python exposition, I made this .i file:

```
%module LibraryInstance
%{
#include "libraryInstance.h"
%}
%include "libraryInstance.h"
```

then I have executed the command `swig -c++ -python -o ./src/libraryInstance_wrap.cpp ./src/libraryInstance.i`

without any output errors, swig has generated two files, `libraryInstance_wrap.cpp` and `LibraryInstance.py`

Then I compile the c++ files, including the `libraryInstance_wrap.cpp`. All compiles fine and I get my library .so file.

when I look into the swig generated `LibraryInstance.py`, I can clearly see the `class LibraryInstance`:

[cf. entire generated python wrapper here.](http://pastebin.com/f8L8KThw)

But when I launch the command `python LibraryInstance.py`, in the same directory as my .so I see this error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LibraryInstance.py", line 26, in <module>
    _LibraryInstance = swig_import_helper()
  File "LibraryInstance.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    import _LibraryInstance
ImportError: No module named _LibraryInstance
```

And when I look in the code of LibraryInstance.py, it just looks as if there has been an exception ImportError thrown, the the module cannot be found by python. ( line 18 ).

Any idea what should I do to correct this ?

Answer (score 5):

In SWIG documentation, [paragraph 31.2.2](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn13) it is stated that the name of the library .so should be `_NameOfTheModule.so`

So I have renammed my library `_LibraryInstance.so`, instead of `LibraryInstance.so`... and now my module loads fine.

Comment: FWIW, the library has to be named _NameOfTheModule.pyd under Windows (since Python 2.5)